UI change suddenly after api call finished
I am making a flutter application which shows some image data load from API and shows to the user.

Like in the above picture UI should look like that even after all the data loaded.
but in my case first two GridView and Listview load correctly, and UI is fine. But after highlightcovers loaded, listview(#animated) jumps to little bit up. Therefore, first GridView now scrollable. But I don't want that because gridview always show 6 images only.
How to solve this issue? If anyone can help me that would be a huge help for me.
Additional note:

ListView's are horizontally scrollable.


This is my ui.
code:
class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homescreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homescreen> createState() => _HomescreenState();
}

class _HomescreenState extends State<Homescreen> {
  bool templatesLoaded = false;
  bool configsLoaded = false;
  bool categoriesLoaded = false;

  List<Category> categories = [];
  List<Template> templates = [];
  List<Collections> collections = [];
  late Config configs;

  List<String> todayImageTemps = [];
  List<String> todayAnimatedImageTemps = [];
  List<String> todayStickers = [];
  List<Collections> todayHighlight = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // _fetchTrendingCategories();
    _fetchCategories();
    // _fetchTemplates();
    _fetchConfigs();
    _fetchCollections();
    context.read<TodayBloc>().add(GetTrendingCategories());
    super.initState();
  }

  void _fetchCategories() {
    context.read<FirebaseBloc>().add(FetchCategories());
  }

  void _fetchTemplates() {
    context.read<FirebaseBloc>().add(FetchTemplates());
  }

  void _fetchCollections() {
    context.read<FirebaseBloc>().add(FetchCollections());
  }

  void _fetchConfigs() {
    context.read<FirebaseBloc>().add(FetchConfig());
  }

  void _getTodayTemplates(
      List<Category> category, List<Template> temps, Config config) {
    debugPrint('All data fetched. Running another method...');
    context.read<TodayBloc>().add(GetTodayTemplates(
        categories: category, randomCount: config.todayRandomCount));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
        child: BlocListener<FirebaseBloc, FirebaseState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is CategoryLoading) {
              debugPrint('loading categories....');
            }

            if (state is CategoryError) {
              debugPrint(state.message);
            }

            if (state is CategoryFetched) {
              categoriesLoaded = true;
              categories = state.categories;
            }

            if (state is CollectionFetched) {
              collections = state.collections;
            }

            // if (state is TemplateFetched) {
            //   templatesLoaded = true;
            //   templates = state.templates;
            // }

            if (state is ConfigFetched) {
              configsLoaded = true;
              configs = state.configs;
            }

            if (categoriesLoaded && configsLoaded) {
              _getTodayTemplates(categories, templates, configs);
            }
          },
          child: BlocConsumer<TodayBloc, TodayState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is LoadingTodayTemplateImages) {
                debugPrint('Loading Images............');
              }

              if (state is TodayTemplateImagesFetched) {
                todayImageTemps = state.imageUrls;
                context.read<TodayBloc>().add(GetAnimatedTemplates());
              }

              if (state is AnimatedTemplateImageFetched) {
                todayAnimatedImageTemps = state.imageUrls;
                context.read<TodayBloc>().add(GetStickerPreview(
                    categories: categories, collectios: collections));
              }

              if (state is StickerPreviewFetched) {
                todayHighlight = state.collectionsDetails;
              }

              if (state is StickerUrlFetched) {
                todayStickers = state.stickerUrl;
              }
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Column(
                // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Today's",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Selection",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (todayImageTemps.isNotEmpty)
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Text(
                        "See All",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (todayImageTemps.isNotEmpty)
                    Expanded(
                      // height: 300,
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8.0, 0, 0),
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: 6,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 80,
                            child: Image.network(
                              todayImageTemps[index],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (todayAnimatedImageTemps.isNotEmpty)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 12.0, 8.0, 0),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          '#animated',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (todayAnimatedImageTemps.isNotEmpty)
                    Expanded(
                      // height: 200,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: todayAnimatedImageTemps.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 100,
                              child: Image.network(
                                todayAnimatedImageTemps[index],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (todayStickers.isNotEmpty)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 12.0, 8.0, 0),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          '#highlightcovers',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (todayStickers.isNotEmpty)
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: todayStickers.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 38.0,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  todayStickers[index],
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

If there is any advice or suggestions for code practices or anything is welcome.

seems like of the child has heights more than other childrens. kindy share ur code.

Please provide a code for let people know what's wrong

apologize for the not adding the code.
